# Display modules only in articles (not in the article list) and only in articles with a specific tag

Tags: joomla-3.x, module, tags, positions

I'm using the J2STORE component on Joomla 3.9.22.
I would need to publish a module in a Blog category but only in the articles (not in the list), in this case the articles are products of j2store.
Also I would like another module to only appear in articles where specific tags are present.
I know that Joomla does not allow this type of assignment so I used the “Advanced Module Manager” component which performs exactly this function but not for j2store articles.

In this regard the developer replies:
"Advanced Module Manager is compatible with it though. Just no a ready-to-use select option for it. You can write a php assignment to check whatever you need. See: https://regularlabs.com/extensions/advancedmodulemanager/faqs#i-want-to-assign-my-module-to-something-not-available-in-the-assignments "

How can I go about solving and getting this I need?

It would be enough just to "activate", as the developer of Advanced Module Manager says, this compatibility with J2store. But I do not know how I can do it.

Comment: Hi there, Since J2Store “articles” (products) are plain Joomla articles created also as J2Store products It is not fully clear from your question why it would not be compatible with regular labs AMM. In Regular Labs AMM Pro you can set modules by tags to Joomla articles thus to J2Store articles too. So I do not see the problem clearly where the incompatibility issue could come from (maybe from your template? I do not know) Please extend your question a bit on this...